# c# Pulling text out of a label and printing the corresponding column in another label

Tags: c#, label

I am new at c# programming and I am stuck. I have a report that pulls the top 12 column names and puts them into 12 labels as the header labels. I also have the one label under each of them that has to have the corresponding data to match the header. The way I have to do this is to take the text(string) out of the header label, let's say header label xrlabel1 displays "good", and find the matching column named "good" and place the value in xrlabel2. I know what to do but have no idea how to accomplish this.

Here is what I have so far:

```
bool match(object value);


    private void xrLabel2_BeforePrint(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintEventArgs e)
    {
        //double holder;
        string zero = 0.ToString();
        object value = xrLabel1.Text;
        bool showDetail = match(value);

       if (showDetail)
        {
            xrLabel2.Text =    Convert.ToString((int)GetCurrentColumnValue(xrLabel1.Text));
        }
        else
        {
           xrLabel2.Text = zero; 
        }


    }
```

Comment: What is failing here? You have given us a piece of code, but haven't told us where the problem is.

Comment: you missed .net strongly typed feature! the code is not so good!

Comment: Sorry. It does not output anything. It just returns a blank. I will let me debug without any errors but it doesn't work. I am looking for suggestions on what I could be doing wrong.

Comment: Any reason why you are using String Zero = 0.ToString();? Just Doesnt make sense to me you could use String Zero = "0"; or string Zero = string.Empty;

Comment: This was based off of an old code I have. I needed to have zero as a string so that I could apply the formatting in the report.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you this organisation

```
   bool showDetail = Match(xrLabel1.Text);
   if (showDetail)
    {
        xrLabel2.Text =    GetCurrentColumnValue(xrLabel1.Text);
    }
    else
    {
       xrLabel2.Text = "0"; 
    }
```

Your methods

```
    private bool Match(string value)
    {
      .....
    }
    private string GetCurrentColumnValue(string value)
    {
      .....
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I would normally use the actual name of the column in the GetCurrentColumnValue("   ") but because I don't know what it is named until the report is generated, it is not working.

Comment: i'am happy to help you Roland, but name is string typed